# Parent Qt to non-qt window with PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, window, parent, qapplication

I am trying to parent a QMainWindow to a non-qt application (the application may change). Any ideas on how to do this?

The qt window opens fine and i can interact with the python API in the applications however the qt window goes behind the application window if i click on the application. I could use Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint flag but then it's on top of everything which isn't ideal.

Psuedo Example:
If you were using an application (example Nuke) where the main application is also qt based you would use something like:

```
def _nuke_main_window():
    """Returns Nuke's main window"""
    for obj in QtWidgets.qApp.topLevelWidgets():
        if (obj.inherits('QMainWindow') and
                obj.metaObject().className() == 'Foundry::UI::DockMainWindow'):
            return obj
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Could not find DockMainWindow instance')

wdg = myWidget(parent=_nuke_main_window())
wdg.show()
```

Maya and any other pyqt based window also would work similarly.

However if the application isnt qt based:

```
wdg = myWidget(parent=nonQtWindowQt_ised)
wdg.show()
```

where:

```
def nonQtWindowQt_ised():
    #return the application main window somehow maybe through python bindings like SIP?
```

Any examples (ideally) or useful direction would be much appreciated.

Using PyQt5, Python 3.5 and Linux.

Comment: Your current question can be described as *too broad*, or *why is not this code working?* so if you do not give specific details is not suitable for SO.

Comment: Sorry, updated. I thought for qt people it would make more sense perhaps.

Comment: What information do you have about the non-Qt application?  Its native window id?

Comment: The only available qt api seems to be [setTransientParent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setTransientParent). However, it doesn't appear to be very reliable (see e.g. [QTBUG-55669](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55669)), and I couldn't get it to work on my linux system at all. What you need is some linux utility that can reliably set [WM_TRANSIENT_FOR](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_TRANSIENT_FOR), but I don't know of any myself.